# Drawing circles in 2d grid array in java

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I understand how to make 2d array grid. I experimented to put random numbers in it but i do not know how to draw them on jframe. For instance, 0 for red circle , 1 for green circle and so on. I need to figure out how represent them in grid manner too.

```
public class Game {


    public static void initGrid(){
        //clumn and row 4 x 4
        int col = 4;
        int row = 4;

        //initialize 2d grid array
        int[][] a = new int[row][col];

        Random rand = new Random();

        //for loop to fill it with random number
        for(int x = 0 ; x < col ; x++) {
            for(int y = 0; y < row; y++) {
                a[x][y] = (int) rand.nextInt(4);
                System.out.print(a[x][y]);
            }//inner for
            System.out.println();
        }//outer for


    }//method


    public static void main(String[] args){
        initGrid();
    }


}
```

I understand JFrame and JPanel as far as drawing on empty canvas but not the way i want. I want to combine both code but my knowledge is limited.

```
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.Graphics2D;
    import java.awt.RenderingHints;
    import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;

  @SuppressWarnings("serial")
  public class Game2 extends JPanel{

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
        g2d.fillOval(0, 0, 30, 30);
        g2d.drawOval(0, 50, 30, 30);
        g2d.fillRect(50, 0, 30, 30);
        g2d.drawRect(50, 50, 30, 30);

        g2d.draw(new Ellipse2D.Double(0, 100, 30 ,30));
    }

     public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Mini Tennis");
        frame.add(new Game2());
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) *"I want to combine both code but my knowledge is limited."*  I want to hear a question.  Do you *have* a question?  If so, what is it? 2) `public class Game2 extends JPanel{

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g){`  for custom painting in a `JComponent` we would override `paintComponent(Graphics)` and immediately call the super method. E.G. `public class Game2 extends JPanel{

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){ super.paintComponent(g);`

Comment: I want to draw those circles on 2d grid and their colors are randomize dependent on the random number it produced e.g 0 for red, 1 for green, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is:

1. Pass the `Game` class as a parameter to the constructor of `Game2` and store it as a local variable in the `Game2` class as illustrated below:

   ```
   Game game;
   public Game2(Game game){
      this.game = game;
      //Rest of your constructor.
   }
   ```
2. Next you declare a getter method in the `Game` class to retrieve the array which stores the position grid like as below:

   ```
   public int[][] getPositions(){
      return this.a;
   }
   ```
3. Create a method that will return the colour to paint based on the `int` value stored as the element of the grid like this:

   ```
   private Color getColor(int col){
      switch(col){
         case 0:
         return Color.red;
         case 1:
         .
         .
         .
         .
      }
   }
   ```
4. Now instead of overriding the `paint` method of your `Game2` class override the `paintComponent` and draw the circles in the `paintComponent` method as illustrated(Here I have considered the circles to be of 30px diameter with a gap of 20px between them):

   ```
   public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
      super.paintComponent(g);
      Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
      int[][] pos = this.game.getPositions();
      for(int i = 0; i < pos.length; i++){
         for(int j = 0; j < pos[i].length; j++){
            g2d.setColor(getColor(pos[i][j]));
            g2d.fillOval(i*50, j*50, 30, 30);
         }
      }
   }
   ```

I hope this will solve your problem of accessing the `Game` representing the model from the `Game2` class representing the view.

Comment: Btw, is there anyway i could pass the initgrid without the game2 super construsctor?  I want to implements mouse listener on the constructor or is it fine to implement it anyway?

Comment: I did not understand your question. Do you mean to say that you do not want to pass the `Game` as parameter? The answer is **no**. If you do not pass the instance you will not get the reference to the instance with which you would be later working.

Comment: Okay thank you, man. I was thinking about adding mouse listener but i haven't grasp on how to do it. Maybe another time for another question.

For now i am happy, i could draw circles in 2d grid.